# Google Docs use multiple accounts without signing out

Tags: google-drive, google-account, google-multi-login

I have four Google accounts and in two of them I use Docs regularly. But I can't switch accounts in Google Docs (in Drive I can):

[image: account sign-in]

As you can see, all other accounts are disabled. On some pages it tells me I must sign out of other accounts first:

> Unavailable unless you sign out of all other Google Accounts and then sign in to this one. Other options

Why? Is there a way to avoid logging out of all other accounts? I can't use incognito mode since I use two-factor authentication.

Comment: Not all Google apps support multiple login.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use incognito/private browsing mode to access a secondary account or in your case, having so many. You might try the multiple user profile method offered by Chrome.

This trick picked up from [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/100999/how-to-use-multiple-profiles-in-google-chrome-like-a-ninja/) were the most concise. You should be able to have many windows open with different profiles active at the same time.

To start using this, go to your `chrome://settings/` and then under **People** you will find an **Add Person** button. You can also pick user images that appear in the top corner of your window to help tell them apart. Each user will have separate sessions, bookmarks and browser settings.

More on this feature in the Chome support at Google

Comment: As I explained, incognito mode is not a good idea. But the profiles might seems a better choice

Comment: Sorry I misread. You are correct, the 2fa adds another hurdle to the login process that would discourage juggling accounts the way you would have to. I also use a shared folder in drive as a tunnel for personal files I might work on while logged in at work.

Comment: Too bad I'm using Firefox, not Chrome. :/